# Python DNA translation

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range, biopython

I have to create my own biopython essentially. Something that can read DNA, transcribe it and translate it. I have gotten it to the point that it can do all of that, but I can't figure out how to get the program to recognize codons in sets of 3 following 'atg' until it reaches a stop codon. Right now it just finds a start codon and then the nearest stop codon without counting by 3's. Can someone help me figure this out? Sorry if this doesn't make sense

```
#locate start codons
startcodon=0
n=0
while(n < 1):
    startcodon=dataset.find("atg", startcodon, len(dataset)-startcodon)
    #locate stop codons
    taacodon=dataset.find("taa", startcodon+3, len(dataset)-startcodon)
    tagcodon=dataset.find("tag", startcodon+3, len(dataset)-startcodon)
    tgacodon=dataset.find("tga", startcodon+3, len(dataset)-startcodon)
    if(taacodon<tagcodon):
        if(taacodon<tgacodon):
            stopcodon=taacodon
            #print("taacodon", startcodon)
        else:
            stopcodon=tgacodon
            #print("tGacodon", startcodon)

    elif(tgacodon>tagcodon):
        stopcodon=tagcodon
        #print("taGcodon", startcodon)
    else:
        stopcodon=tgacodon
        #print("tGacodon", startcodon)
    #to add sequences to an array
    codon.append(dataset[startcodon:stopcodon+3])
    if(startcodon > len(dataset) or startcodon < 0):
        n = 2;
    startcodon=stopcodon

#reverse the string and swap the letters
n=0;
while(n < len(codon)):
        rcodon.append (codon[n][len(codon[n])::-1])
        #replace a with u
        rcodon[n] = re.sub('a', "u", rcodon[n])
        #replace t with a
        rcodon[n] = re.sub('t', "a", rcodon[n])
        #replace c with x
        rcodon[n] = re.sub('c', "x", rcodon[n])
        #replace g with c
        rcodon[n] = re.sub('g', "c", rcodon[n])
        #replace x with g
        rcodon[n] = re.sub('x', "g", rcodon[n])
        print("DNA sequence: ", codon[n] ,'\n', "RNA sequence:", rcodon[n])
        n=n+1
answer = 0
print("Total Sequences:  ", len(codon)-3)
while (int(answer) >=0):
        #str = "Please enter an integer from 0 to " + str(len(dataset)) + " or -1 to quit: "
        answer = int(input("Please enter a sequence you would like to see or -1 to quit:  "))
        if(int(answer) >= 0):
                print("DNA sequence: ", codon[int(answer)] ,'\n', "RNA sequence:", rcodon[int(answer)])
        dna = codon[int(answer)]
        #dna codon table
        protein = {"ttt" : "Phe-", "ctt" : "Leu-", "att" : "Ile-", "gtt" : "Val-",
           "ttc" : "Phe-", "ctc" : "Leu-", "atc" : "Ile-", "gtc" : "Val-",
           "tta" : "Leu-", "cta" : "Leu-", "ata" : "Ile-", "gta" : "Val-",
           "ttg" : "Leu-", "ctg" : "Leu-", "atg" : "Met-", "gtg" : "Val-",
           "tct" : "Ser-", "cct" : "Pro-", "act" : "Thr-", "gct" : "Ala-",
           "tcc" : "Ser-", "ccc" : "Pro-", "acc" : "Thr-", "gcc" : "Ala-",
           "tca" : "Ser-", "cca" : "Pro-", "aca" : "Thr-", "gca" : "Ala-",
           "tcg" : "Ser-", "ccg" : "Pro-", "acg" : "Thr-", "gcg" : "Ala-",
           "tat" : "Tyr-", "cat" : "His-", "aat" : "Asn-", "gat" : "Asp-",
           "tac" : "Tyr-", "cac" : "His-", "aac" : "Asn-", "gac" : "Asp-",
           "taa" : "STOP", "caa" : "Gin-", "aaa" : "Lys-", "gaa" : "Glu-",
           "tag" : "STOP", "cag" : "Gin-", "aag" : "Lys-", "gag" : "Glu-",
           "tgt" : "Cys-", "cgt" : "Arg-", "agt" : "Ser-", "ggt" : "Gly-",
           "tgc" : "Cys-", "cgc" : "Arg-", "agc" : "Ser-", "ggc" : "Gly-",
           "tga" : "STOP", "cga" : "Arg-", "aga" : "Arg-", "gga" : "Gly-",
           "tgg" : "Trp-", "cgg" : "Arg-", "agg" : "Arg-", "ggg" : "Gly-"  
           }
        protein_sequence = ""

        # Generate protein sequence
        for i in range(0, len(dna)-(3+len(dna)%3), 3):
                protein_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+3]]

        # Print the protein sequence
        print ("Protein Sequence: ", protein_sequence)
```

The DNA sequence I have been using starts with "ggtcagaaaaagccctctccatgtctactcacgatacatccctgaaaaccactgaggaagtggcttttcagatcatcttgctttgccagtttggggttgggacttttgccaatgtatttc" so it doesn't start with atg and has to search for it instead. thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it just finds a start codon and then the nearest stop codon without counting by 3's.

If you want to search for a substring aligned to a specific frame (ie an index divisible by 3), you could first split the string into equal chunks and then search the resulting list for a matching chunk.

Eg

```
dataset_codons = [dataset[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(dataset), 3)]
# ggtcagaaaaagccctctcca becomes [ggt cag aaa aag ccc tct cca]

try:
    startcodon = dataset_codons.index('atg', startcodon, len(dataset_codons) - startcodon)
except ValueError:
    break # no more start codons found
```

(note that `startcodon` will then be the index of the chunk matching `atg`, which is exactly 1/3 of the corresponding string index)

Edit: If the stop codon only needs to be on the same frame as its start codon, but the start codon can be anywhere, it becomes a little more tricky. In that case, you could just keep searching for stop codons until you find one whose index is good:

```
def find_codon(codon, string, start):
    i = start + 3
    while i < len(string):
        i = string.find(codon, i) # find the next substring
        if (i - start) % 3 == 0:  # check that it's a multiple of 3 after start
            return i
    return None



startcodon=dataset.find("atg", startcodon)
#locate stop codons
taacodon=find_codon("taa", dataset, startcodon)
tagcodon=find_codon("tag", dataset, startcodon)
tgacodon=find_codon("tga", dataset, startcodon)

stopcodon = min(taacodon, tagcodon, tgacodon)
```

By the way, I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the parameter `len(dataset)-startcodon` correctly. The third argument of `str.find()` specifies the **end** of the search range inside the string, meaning that as `startcodon` increases, the search will stop short of the actual end of the dataset.

Comment: What you edited is more in line with what i am looking for. Where in the code would this be placed?

Comment: Also, how do i make it list each 'chunk' it finds? Like, print the sequence between the start codon and whichever stop codon it finds. Sorry for so many questions, this is my first time using python

Comment: @Lauren the `find_codon()` is a separate function; the other lines replace the respective lines in your loop (between the lines `while (n<1)` and `#to add sequences to an array`). The remainder of your code (including `codon.append(dataset[startcodon:stopcodon+3])` would remain the same, so it still builds tthe list of sequences as before.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find stop codon counting by 3 after start codon, you could split the DNA string after the start codon, and find out whether there is a stop codon inside the codon list.

```py
sequence =  "ggtcagaaaaagccctctccatgtctactcacgatacatccctgaaaaccactgaggaagtggcttttcagatcatcttgctttgccagtttggggttgggacttttgccaatgtatttc"
startcodon = 0
length = len(sequence)
startcodon = sequence.find("atg", startcodon)
# list comprehension. could get codon_list in a for cycle
codon_list = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(startcodon+3, length-3, 3)]

# use list.index() to find out whether there is a stop codon in the codon_list
# list.index() would throw error if value is not in the list
try:
    taacodon = startcodon + 3 * codon_list.index('taa')
    print('taa codon is at {}'.format(taacodon))
except:
    print('taa codon is not in the list')
```

I think splitting the DNA sequence is more efficient than using `str.find`, as you need to search for stop codon counting by *3*, if using `str.find`, you would need to judge whether the found stop codon is at a distance of 3.

---

**Edit**: Currently I don't know whether creating new list of strings would cost more than searching in the original string.

Comment: How would I go about using the locations they are at as breaks instead of just the numerical location?

Comment: Sorry for late response.  I'm not clear about your question in your comment.  If you mean printing the sequences between a start and stop codon, using the location from my splitting method, `dna[startcodon:endcodon_location]` should print it.

Comment: I want to say that on second thought, I find that I'm not sure whether splitting is more efficient, as there would be cost for creating the string list.  This could be another question.  To get better results, I suggest you reading the help for [ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Besides, it is good to ask only one question in a question posted.